# Updating a join model relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

Basically I have a `Shop`, `Category` and a join model `ShopCategory` with additional attributes

```
class Shop
  has_many :shop_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :shop_categories

class Category
  has_many :shop_categories
  has_many :shops, through: :shop_categories

class ShopCategory
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :category
```

I have a shop form which I'd like to create or update the shop through it.

My first thought is to create a virtual attribute called `:categories` and to have the model handle the setter and getter through it, something like this (pseudocode for simplicity):

```
def categories=(cats)

  cats.each do |c|
    check if a ShopCategory exists with this shop (self) and that category.
    if doesn't exist, create one, if exists ignore
    for all the categories in self that weren't touched, delete that ShopCategory
  end

end
```

but I feel this would cause problems in the long run because of the connection of 3 models and not though a controller

However, I can't seem to think of a simple way to have a create and update methods in the shops_controller for handling this

```
def update
 @shop = Shop.find params[:id]

 cats = params[:shop].delete :categories
 @shop.update_attributes(shop_params)

 ## should I have a category update method here? How would I handle errors? This gets complicated

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a **nested model form**, for editing both a Shop and its associated ShopCategories.

Basically, what it entails is on the form for your Shop, you can simply iterate over the associated ShopCategories and print out fields for them, to edit them all together. Rails will automatically handle it all, as long as the parameters are structured correctly.

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon is a gem for making nested model forms easier.

There is also a tutorial on Railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score -1):

**Collections**

I don't know how experienced you are with Ruby on Rails, but you may wish to look at [some of the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) pertaining to *collections*

What you're looking at  is how to populate your *collections* - which is actually relatively simple:

```
#app/controllers/shops_controller.rb
Class ShopsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)
       @shop.save
   end

   private

   def shop_params
      params.require(:shop).permit(:your, :attributes, category_ids: [])
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following form:

```
#app/views/shops/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @shop do |f| %>
   <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
      <%= f.check_box :category_ids, category.id %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Modularity**

In terms of validating your collections for `uniqueness`, you will be best using DB, or Association-level validation:

```
class Shop
  has_many :categories, -> { uniq }, through: :shop_categories
```

This will essentially create only unique categories for your shop, which you can populate with the method described above.

Comment: does that mean I need to add a category_ids as an attribute?

Comment: Yes, but not as a virtual attribute - it should just populate automatically

Comment: Okay, thanks for keeping updated. Let me know when you've tested it out - wonder why someone wanted to downvote...